# Is there a command that displays a message in the screen?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

The only way I found to display a message is in the chat window. I'm looking to display some much bigger and hopefully screen-centered text (visible to yourself only).

Is there such a command available?

Thank you.

Edit:
Well... I'm trying to make a ganking addon (I know it's bad). You store your last victim into a variable and constantly spam that macro to detect if he's back alive and display a message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the API to create dialogs or just bare text

A dialog: `/run message("This is a basic dialog box")`

Text: `/run UIErrorsFrame:AddMessage("Your Message Here", 1.0, 0.5, 0.0, 3);`
Colored orange (1.0, 0.5, 0.0) and 3 seconds long.

If the `UIErrorsFrame` isn't big enough for you, you could create your own frame in the `\run` script and display text there, but I don't know how to do that at the moment :P

Comment: ^^ real answer goes here. Nice.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how to do it with Blizzard's built-in Floating Combat Text, but the ScrollingCombatText add-on provides the exact command you're looking for.

Get it and read about it @ curse's site:
[Scrolling Combat Text (via Curse)](http://wow.curse.com/downloads/wow-addons/details/scrolling-combat-text.aspx)

from the description:

> /sctdisplay is used to create your own custom messages.
>
> Useage:
>
> /sctdisplay 'message' (for white text)
>
> /sctdisplay 'message' red(0-10) green(0-10) blue(0-10)
>
> Example: /sctdisplay 'Heal Me' 10 0 0 - This will display 'Heal Me' in bright red
>
> Some Colors: red = 10 0 0, green = 0 10 0, blue = 0 0 10, yellow = 10 10 0, magenta = 10 0 10, cyan = 0 10 10